# Javascript check length of (this) in function

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have a javascript file that validates a form before posting, here's the form...

```
<form action="#" name="login" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
   <input type="text" name="user"><input type="submit" class="submit">
</form>
```

Here's the javascript...

```
function validate(f) {

    if (f.user.length < 27 || f.user.length > 34) {

    document.getElementById("notice").innerHTML = "Invalid input";

    return false;

    }

return true;

}
```

It doesn't seemed to be firing the "notice" message, why can I not detect the length?

Comment: Try with `f.user.value.length` instead of `f.user.length`.

Comment: Perfecto. Can't believe I missed this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying to check the value of whatever is in the input...
Use the value length not the length of the element.

```
f.user.value.length
```

Comment: @LDK - Don't forget to mark his answer as the correct one.